# why Lists in a class were changed without my operate?

Tags: python-3.x, class

i run a class in a for cycle.
the code is:

```
graph_all = []
graph_now = graph_exc(-1)
for lin in res_str:
    if lin.strip():
        print(lin)
        if lin[0] == 't' :
            if graph_now.numbering != (-1) :
                graph_all.append(graph_now)
            graph_now = graph_exc(int(lin[4:-1]))
        if lin[0] == 'v' :
            graph_now.add_vertex(lin[2],lin[4])
        if lin[0] == 'e' :
            graph_now.add_edges(lin[2],lin[4],lin[6])
    else:
        continue
```

res_str is a list full of sentences.
I use graph_all to accommdate all the class.
when the first letter is 'v' or 'e',i put something in graph_now's lists.
when the first letter is 't',i put graph_now to graph_all and re-define the graph_all.but i find a problem:when i define graph_all again,the lists in class in graph_all will be nothing,too!
the code of graph_exc is :

```
class graph_exc:
    edges_on_1 = []
    edges_on_2 = []
    edges_on_edges = []
    vertex_on = {}
    def __init__(self,numbering):
        self.num_edge = 0
        self.num_vertex = 0
        self.numbering = numbering
        self.edges_on_edges.clear()
        self.edges_on_2.clear()
        self.edges_on_1.clear()
        self.vertex_on.clear()

    def add_vertex(self,ver,ver_num):
        self.vertex_on[ver] = ver_num
        self.num_vertex += 1

    def add_edges(self,point_1,edges,point_2):
        self.edges_on_1.append(point_1)
        self.edges_on_edges.append(edges)
        self.edges_on_2.append(point_2)
        self.num_edge += 1
```

the problem is : edges_on_1,edges_on_edges,edges_on_2 and vertex will be influenced.the data in here will  disappear.but the num_edge and num_vertex are not.
I try to use deepcopy method to solve it.but it does not work.

Comment: Static variables are **shared** between all instances of the class (and the class itself), while instance variables are per instance.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697273/differences-between-static-and-instance-variables-in-python-do-they-even-exist

Comment: thanks a lot.Some classes will share their variables.it's the right answer.